# Sliding view used to control ViewPager paging

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

My goal is to have a sliding view on fragment 1 which slides a set distance before fragment 2 is pulled into visual view.

I made a visual here that shows what I am trying to do:
[image: View slide transition]
Pic 1 Shows the default view of fragment 1 (pink) and sliding view (green), nothing has happened in this state.

Pic 2 The sliding view is able to  slide to it's cutoff (black line). It cannot move past this on this fragment.

Pic 3 The entire fragment 1 begins to slide, fragment 2 (blue) is now starting to be pulled into the view

Pic 4 Both fragments continue to slide as before.

Pic 5 Fragment 2 has now slid into view.

When the user tries to return to the previous screen the transition happens in reverse.

Right now I have implemented a ViewPager which hosts the fragments 1 and 2. The default ViewPager behavior allows me to slide between the two fragments, but I am unsure how to implement the functionality I have described.

Comment: It requires overriding of onTouchListener of the viewPager, inwhich you have to stop passing the events to viewpager until sliding view passes the specified limit.

Comment: You can try to do something with https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.PageTransformer.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired transition with the use of a [ViewPager PageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

I am using [Xamarin.Android](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/) in my project, so C# is used. Although this snippet is in C# it could easily be ported to Java code for use in other projects.

```
float passpoint = 7/8f;

public void TransformPage(View view, float position)
{
    var pageWidth = view.Width;
    var slidingGap = pageWidth - pageWidth * passpoint;
    var translation = position * pageWidth;

    if (position < -1)
    { // [-Infinity,-1)
        // This page is way off-screen to the left.
        view.Alpha = 0;

    }
    else if (position <= 1)
    { // [-1,1]
        var r = new Rect();

        //if valid, this view is the startpage
        Button button = (Button)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.slidingButton);
        if (button != null)
        {
            var posPassPoint = -(1 - passpoint);
            float ratio;
            //create sliding gap
            if (position > posPassPoint)
            {
                ratio = RatioBetween(position, posPassPoint, 0);

                button.TranslationX = slidingGap * -ratio;
            }
            //compensate for sliding gap after it has been reached
            else
            {
                //1- bc want the ratio to shrink
                ratio = 1-RatioBetween(position, -1, posPassPoint);
            }
            view.TranslationX = slidingGap * ratio;
        }

        //valid on views other than start page (no sliding button)
        if (button == null)
        {
            float ratio;
            //create sliding gap
            if (position >= passpoint)
                ratio = RatioBetween(position, passpoint, 1);
            //compensate for sliding gap after it has been reached
            else
                ratio = 1 - RatioBetween(position, 0, passpoint);
            view.TranslationX = slidingGap * ratio;
        }
    }
    else
    { // (1,+Infinity]
        // This page is way off-screen to the right.
        view.Alpha = 0;
    }
}

float RatioBetween(float input, float upperBound, float lowerBound)
{
    return (input - lowerBound) / (upperBound - lowerBound);
}
```